# jQuery's .css() implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I was looking through the jQuery code and found this line:

`elem.runtimeStyle.left = elem.currentStyle.left;`

at

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/449e099b97d823ed0252d8821880bc0e471701ea/src/css.js#L169

I am not sure why this is done. Isn't this useless?

Setting the runtimeStyle to the currentStyle would override nothing. Except make the runtimeStyle readable the next time you read it - which doesn't seem needed now.

I understand the overall concept here and why that code block exists (to convert numeric non-pixel values to the appropriate pixel value, by setting the left to the non-pixel value and reading its pixel value and then reverting the left back to the original value).

**Edit** See my answer below for why I think this is done (with jsFiddle illustration!).

Comment: It is most likely there for IE6 support.

Comment: This is one of the times where a *why* comment would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking about this. Here is why I believe it is done:

Setting the runtimeStyle to the currentStyle ensures that this is style that is applied on the element (the runtime style wins over the inline style). So when you set `elem.style.left` in the next line, there would be no change in the UI. However, the new pixel value can still be calculated using `elem.style.pixelLeft` - because this just converts the non-pixel value on the CSS to a pixel value. `pixelLeft` is not a measurement of the actual position, it is just a conversion to the pixel value.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/RaSzc/

So this is done to figure out the pixel value **without having anything change in the UI**

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an IE hack where the value computed by the RHS of the above is feeded into the LHS of the above. ie.We are getting in new value so as to get the computed value out. Check out this blog to know more about it http://jsperf.com/testing-awesome-hack-for-ie

Comment: I might be missing something here, but I don't understand what you mean by "We are getting in new value so as to get the computed value out". Why is this hack done? The jsperf benchmarks seem to show the hack is slower...

Comment: @Aishwar Its actually reassignment of the value. As in consider.
`var a=10;
var k=20;
x(k);
function x(a)
{
a=a;
}`
I guess its kinda this thing